# How to click on a hyperlink in chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Title says it all. How does one follow through the blue underlined wannabe anchors that are displayed in Chrome Dev Tools?

[image]

Edit: I should have noted that this might be specific to my operating system, Ubuntu. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click (or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>), on the link and then click "Open Link in New Tab". The reason you can't click by default is so that it is more convenient for you to edit the element content. You are more likely to do that in DevTools than follow a link, at least in my case.

[image: Click link in DevTools]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately Ctrl+click doesn't work for me, and neither does Alt-click, Shift-click, Ctrl-Shift-click or any of the other combinations. I should have noted that I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: The shortcut is just to open the context menu. In Linux, I think it's Shift + Fn + F10.